# Deploying Django App with Nginx, Apache, mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, deployment, django, mod-wsgi

I have a django app which can run locally using the standard development environment.  I want to now move this to EC2 for production.  The django documentation suggests running with apache and mod_wsgi, and using nginx for loading static files.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Ec2 box.  My Django app, "ddt", contains a subdirectory "apache" with ddt.wsgi

```
import os, sys
apache_configuration= os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/')
sys.path.append('/home/jeffrey/www/ddt/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ddt.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I have mod_wsgi installed from apt.  My apache/httpd.conf contains

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/ddt.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /home/jeffrey/www/ddt

<Directory /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/>
<Files ddt.wsgi>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Under apache2/sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
<Directory /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/apache_error.log
CustomLog /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/apache_access.log combined
WSGIDaemonProcess datadriventrading.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup datadriventrading.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/ddt.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

If I am correct, these **3 files** above should correctly allow my django app to run on port **8080**.

I have the following nginx/proxy.conf file

```
proxy_redirect              off;
proxy_set_header            Host $host;
proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size        10m;
client_body_buffer_size     128k;
proxy_connect_timeout       90;
proxy_send_timeout          90;
proxy_read_timeout          90;
proxy_buffer_size           4k;
proxy_buffers               4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
```

Under nginx/sites-enabled

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
  access_log /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/nginx_access.log;
  error_log /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/nginx_error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  }
  location  /media/ {
   root /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/;
  }
}
```

If I am correct these two files should setup nginx to take requests on the HTTP port 80, but then direct requests to apache which is running the django app on port 8080.  If i go to mysite.com, all I see is Welcome to Nginx!

Any advice for how to debug this?

Comment: Could you please post your nginx.conf file? there is some problem with nginx not enabling your host, maybe include line is like include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; and your config file is not .conf. Any way if you see nginx welcome page means that your config is not applied.

Comment: For future users, I should mention that with the advent of mod_wsgi-express, we do not need to do _any_ Apache config, no VirtualHost definitions, nothing in conf and sites folders. Its all done in a well-optimized way by mod_wsgi-express automatically. See Graham's blog posts for details

Answer (score 2):

please note, that you should use **www.mysite.com**  or **mysite.com** in your requests(as it defined in config file):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
```

but looks like, You're requesting site by localhost or by IP address

Answer (score 0):

First of all please make sure you can access your application on 127.0.0.1:8080 & please post content of nginx_error.log. Try Copy paste following nginx conf file & check it is working. I am using same config for my python application.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

    location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/www/myproject/webapp;
    }

    }


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NGINX config, you've included the path to the conf file (`/etc/nginx/proxy.conf`) inside a `location`.  I believe that it belongs **outside**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please for the love of all that is holy, don't use both nginx and httpd. This is going to be a pain in the ass to debug.

Secondly, nowhere in the docs have I seen that they recommend this sort of setup.

Use apache or nginx, this will eliminate half of your problems.

Also check your nginx.conf if it's not including files from other dirs, that might have a global vhost that overrides yours.

You should also edit your post to remove the domain in apache config near the WSGI params, as you are currently leaking your production setup.

Remove other sites from sites-enabled.